# TSOA swagger can't generate open api

Tags: typescript, swagger, tsoa

Please help me with this issue.
When running tsoa sagger I am getting following error

`There was a problem resolving type of 'Restaurant'.`

This error occurs only when I extend base entity and make abstract class that I am implementing on restaurant entity.

```
export abstract class BaseModel extends BaseEntity {
  @PrimaryGeneratedColumn()
  id!: number;

  @Index()
  @Column()
  uuid!: string;

  @CreateDateColumn()
  createdAt!: Date;

  @UpdateDateColumn()
  updatedAt!: Date;

  toJSON() {
    return {...this, password: undefined, id: undefined};
  }

  generateUuid() {
    this.uuid = uuid();
  }
}
```

Later in code I am extending Restaurant class with base model

```
@Entity()
export class Restaurant extends BaseModel {
  @Column()
  name!: string;

  @Column({nullable: false})
  userId!: number;
  @ManyToOne((_type) => User, (user: User) => user.restaurants, {
    onDelete: 'CASCADE',
  })
  @JoinColumn()
  user!: User;

  @OneToMany((_type) => Review, (review: Review) => review.restaurant, {
    cascade: true,
  })
  reviews!: Array<Review>;
}
```

Comment: Please also post your `Restaurant` class

Comment: @Helen, I've added restaurant class, thanks :)